# May a Namibian citizen in South Africa on a "Visitor Visa" cross the border into Namibia and return to South Africa the same day?

Tags: south-africa, namibia

I am currently in South Africa with a visitors visa that was stamped at the border for the full 90 days.

Due to some unfortunate travel circumstances I will need to drive to the Namibian border by car to pick up my Parent. (I cannot get them a bus/plane ticket, this is the quickest option, they also have a visitors visa as well)

***Will it be possible for me to cross the S.A. border into Namibia and return the same day back to S.A. ?***

Comment: Is it not possible to walk across the border?

Comment: I think the OP is interested in whether he can easily return to South Africa after collecting his parent.

Comment: Do you really have a South African visa (a sticker in your passport that you applied for at a South African consulate)? Under normal circumstances Namibians can enter South Africa *without a visa* as often as they like for tourism or business, as long as they spend less than 90 days total per year.

Comment: @Max Ah yes this is what I am currently on, I was under the impression that, that "stamp" is a type of visitors visa.

I was wondering with under that would it be possible to return back in the country so suddenly(same day) after crossing the border.

Comment: As a South African citizen myself, as long as you have a valid reason, I see no reason why they should refuse you. I did the Fish River Canoe adventure, and we were actually in both countries regularly along the trip and had no issues with the Border guards - they were very understanding.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of a rule of a minimum time outside of a country before re-entering, and didn't find evidence of one in this case.

As long as you don't exceed the maximum number of entries (usually for visas there is a distinction between single entry and multiple entries, but for visa-free travel there usually isn't, and I couldn't find evidence of such a rule in South Africa) or the maximum number of days per year, I would expect that leaving and quickly re-entering will not be a problem (and I have personally done this between other countries).

If you want a more definitive answer, you might have luck contacting the South African High Commission in Namibia or the South African Department of Home Affairs, or asking the border officials at the crossing.

Once you've asked or tried it, you can post the definitive answer yourself.